# wp insert post with my code on a blank new post

Tags: wordpress, post, insert

i am using this code to create a new page when my plugin is activated:

```
        function create_policy() {
     $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'mobile page',
      'post_content'  => 'this is my content',
      'comment_status' => 'closed',
      'post_type'     => 'page',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => array( 3,4 )
      );
      wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    }


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_policy' );
```

what i want to do is :
1) use my own code in the 'post_content', not regular text.
2) clear all the page and leave only the GET_header
i want a blank page with my code.

any advice ?

**in addition to the comments:**

this is the admin pannel code:

```
<?php

// create custom plugin settings menu  
add_action('admin_menu', 'zeev_create_menu');  

function zeev_create_menu() {  

    //create new top-level menu  
    add_menu_page('zeev movile redirect', 'zeev mobile', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'zeev_settings_page', 'favicon.ico');  

    //call register settings function  
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );  
}  
function register_mysettings() {  
    //register our settings  
    register_setting( 'zeev-settings-group', 'zeev_tracking_code' );  
} 
function zeev_settings_page() {  
?>  
<div class="wrap">  

<form method="post" action="options.php">  

    <?php settings_fields('zeev-settings-group'); ?>  
    <table class="form-table">  

        <tr valign="top">  
        <td><textarea name="zeev_tracking_code" cols="90"><?php echo get_option('zeev_tracking_code'); ?></textarea></td>  
        </tr>  

    </table>  

    <p class="submit">  
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />  
    </p>  

</form>  
</div>  
<?php }
```

and this is the veriable what need to find himself on a blank page someware (and to work)

```
<?php echo get_option('zeev_tracking_code'); ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to store PHP or HTML code in the `post_content` property, and when you visit that URL, it returns a blank page, but runs your code?

Comment: yes, that is what i want !

Comment: That's crazy :) Posts aren't really designed to run code like that. What you want is to build separate templates and put the code into them. Is it PHP you want to run on each post? If so, give me a couple of examples of what a couple of posts would do, and I'll try show you how to do it

Comment: well... what is hapening is that i build a plugin that will do that: if a user is coming from a mobile phone he will be redirected into a page where he will se 2 buttons "normal site", "mobile site". i made a control panel for that plugin and created some fields with wordpress Options API.. no the admin will pased the url to the mobile site and the normal and the button will redirect the surfer.
my problem is that i need a blank page that will be able to contain the veriables from the plugin admin panel. so i was thinking of using the post/page template, that is how i got here.any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, I think what you're looking for is templates. See my answer.

Comment: Why not just update your theme to do responsive design? Use a search engine to learn how.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get custom layouts in Wordpress on a page-by-page basis, but the most common is to create a new, custom template. In the theme folder, create a new file named what you like:

```
my-custom-template.php
```

The easiest way to start is to copy what you find in `page.php` into that directory.  That will give you the structure with the headers and footers which are useful. Right at the top of the file, put:

```
<?php
/*
*
* Template Name: [My template]
*
*/
?>
```

Doing this will tell WP to automatically make this template an option when creating a new page. Now, when you create a page, you can select this template from the dropdown, and the page will use that.  Inside the template itself, you can put whatever PHP or HTML code you need inbetween the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` you like, to style it, or just to show your two buttons.

If you want a totally blank page, you can remove the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` altogether.

Comment: hi, i know i can do this manually. the problem is that i am building a plugin and i want it to do this automatically for the user..

Comment: ok the solution was to include the wo-config.php in the page i wanted to put my variables.. it dosn't matter where the page is, if it has wp-config, the variables from the admin will work